# Check if an Object is an Array or a Dict

Tags: julia

I'd like to check if var is an Array or a Dict.

```
typeof(var) == Dict

typeof(var) == Array
```

But it doesn't work because typeof is too precise: Dict{ASCIIString,Int64}.
What's the best way ?

Comment: So you are looking to find just a generic type _(either "Dict" or "Array")_?

Comment: Yes exactly ! "Dict" or "Array"

Comment: The answers are good, but you could also just replace `==` in your question with `<:` and get the result you're after. The `<:` operator checks whether `typeof(var)` is a subtype of the type on the right hand side of the expression. For what it's worth, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: Yes, my point was just that you should use the abstract type instead of a concrete type if you are going to use `isa` (`<:`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need a "less precise" check, you may want to consider using the [`isa()`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/?highlight=isa#Base.isa) function, like this:

```
julia> d = Dict([("A", 1), ("B", 2)])
julia> isa(d, Dict)
true
julia> isa(d, Array)
false

julia> a = rand(1,2,3);
julia> isa(a, Dict)
false
julia> isa(a, Array)
true
```

The `isa()` function could then be used in [control flow constructs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/control-flow/), like this:

```
julia> if isa(d, Dict)
         println("I'm a dictionary!")
       end
I'm a dictionary!

julia> if isa(a, Array)
         println("I'm an array!")
       end
I'm an array!
```

---

**Note:** Tested with Julia 0.4.3

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking for a particular concrete type, such as Array, or Dict, you might do better by checking for the abstract types, and gain a lot of flexibility.

For example:

```
julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
julia> d = Dict(:a=>1,:b=>2)
Dict(:a=>1,:b=>2)
julia> isa(d, Associative)
true
julia> isa(x, AbstractArray)
true
```

There are many different types of arrays in Julia, so checking for `Array` is likely to be too restrictive, you won't get sparse matrices, for example.
There are also a number of different types of associative structures, `Dict`, `ObjectIdDict`, `SortedDict`, `OrderedDict`.

Comment: `isa(d, Associative)` does not work for me on `Julia 1.6.0`. I guess it was removed since `supertype(AbstractDict)` returns `Any`.

Comment: My answer was back from version v0.4 of Julia, and a lot of things changed before things became stable with the release of v1.0 in August of 2018.
You should use `isa(d, AbstractDict)` instead.